# Xayah's Passive Damage

Tags: league-of-legends

Xayah

**Passive: Clean Cuts**

> INNATE: After casting an ability, Xayah's next 3 basic attacks
>   penetrate all enemies along their path, dealing 100% damage to her
>   main target and 50% pass-through damage to other enemies. At her
>   maximum attack range, a Feather will be left in the ground for 6
>   seconds. Xayah can store up to 5 empowered attacks.

---

When the passive hits additional enemies, does the other targets take 50% of damage that the initial target took or is it 50% of Xayah's AD?

For example, if Xayah does 100 physical damage + 20 physical damage from BoTRK's passive, would the target take 100/2=50 physical damage or (100+20)/2=60 physical damage?

Comment: Off the top of my head I'd say the on-hit effect of BotRK is only applied to the first target (think about what would happen with on-hit magic damage like Nashor's Tooth) but then I couldn't say for sure without testing it. On-Hit effects behave weirdly in situations like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After doing some research I stumbled upon **[this reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/summonerschool/comments/66feoo/strange_xayah_and_rakan_combat_interactions/)** which confirms my suspicions.

Xayah's autoattacks will still apply an on-hit effect to the her initial target, however all subsequent targets will take damage based on the **incoming attack without on-hit effects**.

As pointed out in the reddit thread her passive is more comparable to a Kayle E than to a Twitch R/Runaan's Hurricane.

In the case you've described above Xayah would deal **120 damage** to the primary target and her feathers would deal **50 damage** to subsequent targets.
Please note that the incoming attack could critically strike, resulting in the attack dealing **220 damage** to the primary target but only **100 damage** to the secondary target(s).

Answer (score 1):

According to http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Xayah (click show ability details)

> On-hit effects are only applied to her selected attack target

BotRK's passive is an on-hit effect, so in your example, the target you attacked would take 100+20=120 damage, and other targets would take 100/2=50 damage.
These numbers would also be reduces by the individual targets armor.

basically, the main target takes 100% AD + on-hit damage, and the other targets take 50% AD damge.

Answer (score 0):

The damage isn't calculated on specific bonus ad or basic ad but on your autoattack damage.

So in your example your enemy (the one you clicked on) is going to take 120 damage (from the attack) and the other enemies are going to take 50 damage because botrk on hit attack is not calculated in the process.

Obviously if the targets have different armor, the damage is going to be different.

Answer (score -1):

It deals 100% (deals the original damage) to the first target, and half of that to other targets.

In other words, the first target takes double damage than the others